# How to delete a node in XML, if I have attribute ID and value if node under that album ID

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<Albums>
  <Album ID="ankit">
    <AlbumName>Jaipur Tour</AlbumName>
    <AlbumName>Shimla Tour</AlbumName>
    <AlbumName>Andaman Tour</AlbumName>
    <AlbumName>France Tour</AlbumName>
  </Album>
  <Album ID="amit">
    <AlbumName>Goa Tour</AlbumName>
    <AlbumName>China Tour</AlbumName>
    <AlbumName>Panama Tour</AlbumName> // delete this node
    <AlbumName>Europe Tour</AlbumName>
  </Album>
</Albums>
```

To delete album from album.xml where userid is given and under that userid album name is given

```
var qryAlbum = from element in loadAlbum.Descendants("Album")
where (string)element.Attribute("ID") == UIDLabel.Text
select element;
qryAlbum.Descendants("Album").Elements("AlbumName").Where(x => x.Value == albumSelected).Remove();

 loadAlbum.Save(@"D:\PhotoFrame\Album.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *select* an element that you want to delete.

```
 var element = loadAlbum.Descendants("AlbumName")
                        .Where(x => x.Value == "Panama Tour" 
                         && x.Parent.Attribute("ID").Value == "amit" )
                        .FirstOrDefault();
 if (element != null)
  {
   element.Remove();
   loadAlbum.Save(@"file.xml");
  }
```

EDIT:To replace the `text`

```
if (element != null)
      {
       element.Value = "New Value";
       loadAlbum.Save(@"file.xml");
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much... What if I have to edit the value not delete it??

Comment: Set the value property : `element.Value = "New Value";`